# pyspark dataframe: add a new indicator column with random sampling

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark dataframe containing the following schema:

```
StructField(email_address,StringType,true),StructField(subject_line,StringType,true)))
```

I want randomly sample 50% of the population into control and test. Currently I am doing it the following way:

```
df_segment_ctl = df_segment.sample(False, 0.5, seed=0)
df_segment_tmt = df_segment.join(df_segment_ctl, ["email_address"], "leftanti")
```

But I am certain there must be a better way to create a column instead like the following

```
|       email_address|     segment_id|group    |
+--------------------+---------------+---------+
|xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com|            1.1|treatment|
|   xxxxxxx@gmail.com|            1.6|control  |
```

Any help is appreciated. I am new to this world

UPDATE:
I dont want to split the dataframe into two. Just want to add an indicator column

UPDATE:
Is it possible to have multiple splits elegantly. Suppose instead of two groups I want a single control and two treatment

```
    |       email_address|     segment_id|group    | 
    +--------------------+---------------+---------+
    |xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com|            1.1|treat_1. | 
    |   xxxxxxx@gmail.com|            1.6|control  |
    |   xxxxx@gmail.com  |            1.6|treat_2  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the spark dataframe using random split like below

```
df_segment_ctl, df_segment_tmt = df_segment.randomSplit(weights=[0.5,0.5], seed=0)
```